# Cannot startx, protocol not found

Tags: xorg, startup, installation, dependencies, re-installation

Good afternoon,

I cannot startx, I get an error "Protocol not found".

(Ubuntu 11.10 x86_64 install was messed up after libjpeg was removed, had to reinstall ubuntu-desktop)

Is there anything I can do to get this working again?

Thanks for all suggestions,

Alec Taylor

Comment: My Xorg.0.log: http://pastebin.com/XL4GpL9X
My xorg.conf: http://pastebin.com/0cQdjvH3

Answer (score 1):

run `sudo apt-get install libjpeg`

packages it might have uninstalled: compiz, unity, vino,

Comment: I've already reinstalled libjpeg and ubuntu-desktop.